# Wordpress - CPT child of given Page using ACP

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, permalinks

I'm trying to change the permalink of my CPT 'book-name' by making it the child of a default page 'genre-name'. I don't use meta box for various reasons, so the only solution is ACF.

So in the CPT I will have a selector for the parent page - 'genre-name'.

The problem is that ACF is returning a wp_post object. How can I work with this in order to make the change on the permalink and to make it the parent of my CPT?

I followed a tutorial that was using meta boxes, but I'm lost now....

Tried a lot of things, this is what I have now:

```
function rewrite_url_for_books() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%book%', '([^/]+)', 'book=');
  add_permastruct('book', '/%genre%/%book%', false);
  add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+/([^/]+/?', 'index.php?book=$matches[2]', 'top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_url_for_book' );

function permalink_for_book($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  $post_id = $post->ID;
  if($post->post_type != 'book' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
    return $permalink;

  $genre = get_field('genre_field');
  setup_postdata($genre);


  $parent = $post->post_parent;
  $parent_post = get_post($parent);

  $permalink = str_replace('%genre%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);

  return $permalink;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'permalink_for_book', 10, 3);
```

This is a wp_post object

```
WP_Post (object) => [
    // Default data returned by WP_Post
    ID                  => int,
    post_author         => string,
    post_name           => string,
    post_type           => string,
    post_title          => string,
    post_date           => string,
    post_date_gmt       => string,
    post_content        => string,
    post_excerpt        => string,
    post_status         => string,
    comment_status      => string,
    ping_status         => string,
    post_password       => string,
    post_parent         => int,
    post_modified       => string,
    post_modified_gmt   => string,
    comment_count       => string,
    menu_order          => string,

    // Additional data I want to add
    extra_data_1        => array,
    more_data_key       => string,
    another_added       => string
]
```

Comment: I don't know where in the bootstraping sequence the URL is generated, but I feel it's before you hit this filter. That might be the issue.